# Socket program unable to POST - C (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, post

**Issue :**

We  are able to successfully communicate with the server but unable
 to post the message. Because the server responded 
`"Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand"`. This happened when the format of below strings was wrong.

**Sample Code:**

```
"POST /evs/getServerAddress?uid=abcd&pwd=abcd HTTP/1.1\r\n";
"Host: https://evs.idrive.com\r\n";
"Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

//#include<sys/socket.h>
//sockfd is socket
//above three strings are passed as option_value1, option_value2 and option value3 
send(sockfd, option_value1, sizeof(option_value1), 1);
send(sockfd, option_value2, sizeof(option_value2), 1);
send(sockfd, option_value3, sizeof(option_value3), 1);
```

**Problem:** 
      Now server is not responding to anything. Kindly let me know several approaches to get the response from server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the server logs - is the service still running?

Comment: Use `strlen()` instead of `sizeof()`, and fix the `Host` header, its value is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code here.

1. As Remy LeBeau mentioned, the value you are sending for the `Host` header is wrong. It should not contain the `https://` prefix.
2. Also as mentioned, you should be sending these strings with the length determined by `strlen()`, not `sizeof()`. Even if you are taking the size of a character array (not a pointer), that would still end up a byte too long.
3. The final `flags` argument to `send()` should be `0`, not `1`. Setting it to `1` (`MSG_OOB`) causes your data to be transmitted as out-of-band data, which is almost never something you want.
4. You are not checking the return value of `send()`. You really should be - `send()` may not always send all bytes requested.
5. Most importantly: your POST request is malformed. It contains no body and no `Content-Length` / `Content-Type`. It looks as though you are trying to pass POST variables in the URL, but that is what you do with a GET request, not a POST. A proper POST request would look like:

   ```
   POST /evs/getServerAddress HTTP/1.1
   Host: evs.idrive.com
   Content-Type: multipart/x-www-form-urlencoded
   Content-Length: 17

   uid=abcd&pwd=abcd
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
send(sockfd, option_value1, sizeof(option_value1), 1);
```

`sizeof(option_value1)` will evaluate to the size of a pointer. Depending on your system this may or may not be 4 bytes. Thus you are sending only 4, or whatever your system's pointer size is, bytes of the string.

To get the length of the string use `strlen(option_value1)`.

You can check what you're transmitting by using a program call [***WireShark***](http://www.wireshark.org/). Its free and will be able to show you what's going on on your network connection... what you're sending and what you're receiving. WireShark will also tell you if the HTTP packets you're sending are malformed....

If the server is not responding to your program, is it responding to ping requests. This is a useful tool. If it is responding to pings then you can be more confident the server is ok, if not then you know to restart the server.